# SASM Debugger not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm, sasm

I have a problem with SASM.
If I try to start the Debugger via SASM, it does not stop at my Breakpoint.

The output:

```
[18:50:03] Build started...
[18:50:03] Built successfully.
[18:50:03] Debugging started...
[18:50:04] Debugging finished.
```

As you can see the Debugger does not stop at the beginning of my `CMAIN:` where I set the breakpoint via *F8*.

My settings in SASM:
[image: SASM Settings]

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Does execution reach `CMAIN` in the first place?  That's a pretty random symbol name; nothing jumps there automatically or uses it as the entry point name by default.  Since you're on Linux (or some other `-felf32` target) and aren't using `-nostdlib`, gcc will link CRT startup code that calls `main`, not `CMAIN`.

Comment: You can use `starti` to stop before the first user-space instruction of your process to see where execution actually does go.  (That will be in the dynamic linker aka ELF interpreter, `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, unless you link with `-static`.)